# DOSBox and Blinker SWPRUNCMD

Tags: dosbox, clipper

I have a Clipper 5.3 app linker using Blinker designed for DOS PCs.  I use the Blinker SWPRUNCMD() to swap to DOS and other programs.  Needing to run this program in a Win 7 Pro 64 bit environment, I tried DOSBox 0.74.  The only problem I have found so far is that when the SWPRUNCMD() is executed, the message 'Swap Failed' displays.  Currently, I do not have the ability to recompile (although I may be able to re-link) so cannot try the native Clipper RUN command.  Could anyone help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but I'll write it anyway: we have a Clipper app at work which doesn't run on Windows 7 (for some reason, I don't know whether it's related to your problem), so the people using it have a Windows XP virtual machine. I think that app does work in DOSBox too, though.

Answer (score 0):

Using RUN instead of SWPRUNCMD() is going to be problematic, as RUN does not swap out memory before running the other binary. If the other binary has large memory requirements, RUN won't be much help.

Wikipedia does mention other [dos emulators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aDOS_emulators) but, oddly, doesn't mention [BOCHS](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

see [SET CLIPPER](http://www.itlnet.net/programming/program/Reference/c53g04c/nga092.html) information, particularly //SWAPPATH option.

Also, you can run your app with:

```
app //INFO > log.txt
```

to get more info in log.txt